# Matlab locks when I try opening a PointGrey BlackFly camera as GigE or WinVideo imaq.VideoDevice if the camera is open in FlyCapture2 - How stop?

Tags: matlab, camera

How can I prevent Matlab locking when I try opening a PointGrey BlackFly camera as a GigE or WinVideo imaq.VideoDevice, if the camera is already open in FlyCapture2?

My code

```
if ~ exist('videoDevice','var') 
  videoDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 2, 'RGB24_1288x728');  
end
```

95% of the time blocks and hangs Matlab if the camera is already open in FlyCapture2.

System: Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-Bit, Matlab 2016a, FlyCapture2 2.9.3 or 2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can activate FlyCapture2 and Image Acquisition toolbox simultaneously.
The best advice I can give you is to check if FlyCapture2 process is running before opening the device in Matlab.

Test if FlyCapture2 is running:

```
[status, result] = system('tasklist /FI "imagename eq Point Grey FlyCap2.exe" /fo table /nh');
```

result (when running):

```
Point Grey FlyCap2.exe       46820 Console                    3     43,232 K
```

You can display a warning message and/or terminate FlyCap2.exe process:

```
[status, result] = system('tasklist /FI "imagename eq Point Grey FlyCap2.exe" /fo table /nh');

if (~isempty(strfind(result, 'FlyCap2.exe')))
    %Display warning, and wait for user to press OK.
    waitfor(warndlg('FlyCap2.exe process is running'));

    %Terminate FlyCap2.exe process.
    system('taskkill /f /im "Point Grey FlyCap2.exe"');
end

%Open device...
if ~ exist('videoDevice','var') 
  videoDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 2, 'RGB24_1288x728');  
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!   I will try that this afternoon.